# make UILabel's text bold

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, uifont, textcolor

I want to make UILabel's text bold

```
infoLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(90,150, 200, 30)];
[infoLabel setText:@"Drag 14 more Flavors"];
[infoLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[infoLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]];

[infoLabel setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:193.0/255 
                                        green:27.0/255 
                                         blue:23.0/255 
                                        alpha:1 ]];
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Try

```
[infoLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:16]];
```

It may also be worth checking if the font you're trying to use is available on device

Comment: It would be nice to merge this answer and the one below: If you want to retain the system font and make it bold:

[infoLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];

Answer (score 133):

If you want to retain the system font and make it bold:

```
[infoLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
```

Comment: And if you want to retain the size:    [infoLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: infoLabel.font.pointSize]];

Answer (score 44):

Using the GUI in Xcode select the label then go to the Attributes Inspector.  One of the options is Font.  Click on the font icon (not the up-down arrows).  In the popup that appears expand the Font ComboxBox.  Under the Bold System section choose Regular.

[image: Xcode screenshot]

Answer (score 17):

For swift users this should work:

```
myLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12.0)
```

or if you'd like to use a different font:

```
myLabel.font = UIFont(name:"HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 12.0)
```

Answer (score 6):

Where possible I would suggest using dynamic font sizes to provide the best possible accessibility to your users.

You can make a label use a system dynamic font and set it to have bold text by doing the following:

```
 exampleLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body, compatibleWith: UITraitCollection(legibilityWeight: .bold))
```

Comment: I tried this just for fun ... didn't work.

Comment: Worked for me. That having been said, when I want to use custom fonts/styles in my app, but want it to size dynamically, I often use [`scaledFont`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifontmetrics/2877385-scaledfont). E.g., `UIFontMetrics.default.scaledFont(for: customFont)`.

Comment: But, fundamentally, I think this answer is correct, that one should almost never use fixed font sizes within an app. Dynamic type is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the stroke with a negative value to make a bold effect if you don't have the bold variation of your custom font. See here:

[How can I both stroke and fill with NSAttributedString w/ UILabel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16047901/how-can-i-both-stroke-and-fill-with-nsattributedstring-w-uilabel)