# How can I get my attributed string to work again

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsattributedstring

I have an app in which I was using the following code to create an outlined text for my labels.

```
self.label1.attributedText = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fourthString attributes:@{NSStrokeColorAttributeName:[UIColor blackColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor],NSStrokeWidthAttributeName:@-2.0}];
```

All of the sudden it stopped working with the warning
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16b5c7e50)
and could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

If I change it to

```
self.label2.text = fourthString:
```

it works fine.  What happened

Comment: can you try the code in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16047902/4061501)?

Comment: I tried it and NO go.  I got the same warnings.  Thanks

Comment: Are you using custom class for that label?

Comment: I am creating them trough code and then added them as a subView.  The view that I am adding them to is a view that also adds an overlay view on my camera.  Problem is I don't remember doing anything and now it doesn't work when it did before

Comment: is that UILabel? or did you create custom class for UILabel?

Comment: it is a UILabel

Comment: I would recommend profiling the code in Instruments (command-i) and use the “Zombies” instrument.